# React-facebook-login work only for one account

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, facebook-login

Hello I have implemented react facebook login package in my app. However it works only for one account. I can't get login info data with another account. Here is my code:

```
    const registerFb = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const newUser = new UsersSchema({
    email: req.body.email,
  });
  try {
    const existEmail = await UsersSchema.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (existEmail) {
      const token = jwt.sign({ email: req.body.email }, "privKey");
      res.send(token);
    } else {
      const savedUser = await newUser.save();
      res.send(savedUser);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

Comment: If you figured this out please update with answer. I have same problem in development mode and windering if I switch to production mode if it'll solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Is your app still in development mode? If so, you can only test with specified users -- and the person who set-up the app is one of the specified users by default.

You can add more testing users under Roles in the App Dashboard.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If the app is in production mode will it work with other accounts? How can I configure my app to work with all accounts?